# Magento2: "Could not read config file" when enabling developer mode

Tags: magento2

If I enable developer mode in magento 2 I get the following error:

```
Could not read config file
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(113): Magento\Framework\Config\FileResolver->get('view.xml', 'global')
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/View.php(210): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read()
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/Config/View.php(87): Magento\Framework\Config\View->initData()
#3 /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(833): Magento\Framework\Config\View->getVarValue('Magento_Catalog', 'product_image_w...')
#4 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(75): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getFrame()
#5 /var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#6 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(65): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getConfig()
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#10 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml(45): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getConfig()
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/mount/...')
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor), '/var/www/mount/...', Array)
#13 /var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(297): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/mount/...')
#14 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/mount/...')
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(609): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->toHtml()
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('minicart')
#19 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('minicart')
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('minicart')
#21 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('minicart', true)
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('minicart')
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header-wrapper')
#24 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header-wrapper')
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('header-wrapper')
#26 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header-wrapper', true)
#27 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('header-wrapper')
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header.containe...')
#29 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#30 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#31 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.containe...', true)
#32 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('header.containe...')
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#34 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#36 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#37 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#38 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#39 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#40 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#41 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#42 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#43 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#44 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#46 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#47 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#48 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#49 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#50 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#51 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#52 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#53 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#54 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#55 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#56 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#57 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#58 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#59 /var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#60 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#61 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#62 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#63 {main}
```

Anyone an idea to solve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

some of your xml files don't have read permissions.
The exception is thrown [from here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/FileResolver.php#L107).
As you can see in the code, the file exists, because you end up inside `if (file_exists($designPath)) {`.
So you either you don't have read rights, or the file is not properly formatted.
You can add before the `throw` statement this `echo $e->getMessage();exit;` to see on the screen what's the exact error.

```
if (file_exists($designPath)) {
    try {
        $designDom = new \DOMDocument;
        $designDom->load($designPath);
        $iterator[$designPath] = $designDom->saveXML();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The Problem was my custom theme which contains an empty view.xml file. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: in my case was the circled C of Copyright that was in a comment at the beginning of `view.xml` and that was not encoded properly... Thanks for the hint as well

Comment: @Memes, thank you for the tip, I had the same issue and after removing the copyright symbol, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the problem is that, in the Magento2 development model, the PHP system will validate the URL in the namespace of the XML file, and if not, it will show "could not read config file" error message. So you should turn off the detection of the parameter, add the code of below into the `index.php`: `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)`

I hope this can help you. and I fix the problem use it.

For more information you can check the article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489845/php-warning-domdocumentload-i-o-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity