# Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException : Could not read config file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I created a new theme in magento2, after creating theme, I reloaded my local site, getting this issue.

[image: this is the exception i am getting]

Comment: refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93890/36463

Answer (score 3):

The error is self explained. **Your custom theme is missing `view.xml` config or the config is not correct**.

Read more about `view.xml`: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html