# Magento 2 could not read config file after clearing cache

Tags: magento2

I broke everything; can't even connect to the dashboard T_T I think it happened when I was trying to clear the cache to see if some frontend changes were being reflected.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Could not read config file

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Could not read config file
#0 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(123): Magento\Framework\Config\FileResolver->get('view.xml', 'global')
```

Where do I even start trying to fix this? What about clearing the cache or extending a theme could have caused such a fundamental crash?

I didn't even know my site had a View.xml file at the global level...

Edit: (rest of the stack trace)

```
#1 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Config/View.php(233): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('global')
#2 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Config/View.php(213): Magento\Framework\Config\View->read()
#3 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Config/View.php(90): Magento\Framework\Config\View->initData()
#4 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php(833): Magento\Framework\Config\View->getVarValue('Magento_Catalog', 'product_image_w...')
#5 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(81): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getFrame()
#6 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#7 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(70): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#8 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getConfig()
#9 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml(46): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getConfig()
#11 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/frienb...')
#12 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Decorator/DebugHints.php(42): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor), '/var/www/frienb...', Array)
#13 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Decorator\DebugHints->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor), '/var/www/frienb...', Array)
#14 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(297): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/frienb...')
#15 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/frienb...')
#16 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar/Interceptor.php(609): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->toHtml()
#19 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('minicart')
#20 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('minicart')
#21 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('minicart')
#22 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('minicart', true)
#23 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('minicart')
#24 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header-wrapper')
#25 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header-wrapper')
#26 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('header-wrapper')
#27 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header-wrapper', true)
#28 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('header-wrapper')
#29 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('header.containe...')
#30 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#31 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('header.containe...')
#32 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('header.containe...', true)
#33 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('header.containe...')
#34 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#35 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#36 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#37 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#38 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#39 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#40 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#41 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#42 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#43 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#44 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#45 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#46 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#47 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#48 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#49 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#50 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#51 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#52 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#53 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#54 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#55 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#56 /var/www/frienbr/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#57 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#58 /var/www/frienbr/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#59 /var/www/frienbr/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#60 {main}
```

Comment: Never seen this error before but try this. In ssh:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Check permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when one of your config or layout XML files doesn't have the right permissions, or if one of the XML files is empty.

More info here: [Magento2: "Could not read config file" when enabling developer mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93889/magento2-could-not-read-config-file-when-enabling-developer-mode)

In addition, maybe just running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` will fix the error.

Comment: Thank you yes that was what I needed... So many dots...